# JXDatePicker with unselectabledate for all the month

Tags: java, datepicker

Currently I'm using `JXDatePicker` from `org.jdesktop.swingx.JXDatePicker`; This is a code I applied on my picker to cross out some dates that I don't want the user to pick

```
picker.getMonthView().setUnselectableDates(dateArray);
```

But there is a problem, when the user starts to choose a date, and he clicked on the next month button which is located on the top left and top right corner of the date picker, the `setUnselectableDates` does not affect the next month.

What should I do in order to detect month change action or apply this to all the months in the picker?

Comment: So instead of specific dates, you want e.g. every third day of every month being unselectable?

Comment: The question can be improved by adding the swingx tag. That may attract observers of that tag to answer this question.

Comment: The question is fixed, is just my mistake for not setting the date on the next month to be unselectable. It seems the setUnselectableDates function will set for every month as well. Thanks.